# How to start a new column in flex column wrap layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I want my data to be arranged in columns (top to bottom, left to right) and every heading inside the data should start a new column. There are three constraints:

- Must use flex (I need to use a feature specific to flex)
- Cannot group the data (e.g. wrap all data items inside one div)
- Cannot set fixed height

My question is how do I *force* a column break inside a `flex-flow: column` wrap layout?

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.grid .head {
  width: 25%;
  background: orange;
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
}
.grid .data {
  width: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
}
/* my attempt to solve this */
.grid {
  height: 76px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="head">Column 1 (3 items)</div>
  <div class="data">item 1-1</div>
  <div class="data">item 1-2</div>
  <div class="data">item 1-3</div>
  <div class="head">Column 2 (4 items)</div>
  <div class="data">item 2-1</div>
  <div class="data">item 2-2</div>
  <div class="data">item 2-3</div>
  <div class="data">item 2-4</div>
  <div class="head">Column 3 (2 items)</div>
  <div class="data">item 3-1</div>
  <div class="data">item 3-2</div>
  <div class="head">Column 4 (1 items)</div>
  <div class="data">item 4-1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This probably wont fit your needs, but [I made this with the default row direction and empty divs](http://jsbin.com/juceq/4/edit?html,css,output)... it's a bit dirty.

Comment: Would you be interested in a solution which uses `column-count`? Flex and column-count don't play well together, but maybe if flex is applied on a parent element you might be able to use them both

Comment: That will not work for me but it could help someone else with similar problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently, [the correct solution is to use the `break-before` or `break-after` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#main-sizing):

> A break is forced wherever the CSS2.1
> [page-break-before](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#propdef-page-break-before)/[page-break-after](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#propdef-page-break-after) [CSS21] or the CSS3
> [break-before](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-break/#break-before)/[break-after](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-break/#break-after) [CSS3-BREAK] properties specify a
> fragmentation break.

At the time of writing, most browsers implement the `*-break-*` properties incorrectly or do not implement them at all. Consider this answer ahead of its time.

The following demo works in:

- FF33

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.grid .head {
  width: 25%;
  background: orange;
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
}
.grid .data {
  width: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
}
/* force column breaks */
.grid .head:nth-child(n + 2) {
  page-break-before: always; /* FF33 */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="head">Column 1 (3 items)</div>
  <div class="data">item 1-1</div>
  <div class="data">item 1-2</div>
  <div class="data">item 1-3</div>
  <div class="head">Column 2 (4 items)</div>
  <div class="data">item 2-1</div>
  <div class="data">item 2-2</div>
  <div class="data">item 2-3</div>
  <div class="data">item 2-4</div>
  <div class="head">Column 3 (2 items)</div>
  <div class="data">item 3-1</div>
  <div class="data">item 3-2</div>
  <div class="head">Column 4 (1 items)</div>
  <div class="data">item 4-1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not supported in Chrome 47 I currently use

Comment: Sadly, this is still not supported.

Comment: Still not supported in November 2020.

Comment: Still not supported in September 2021

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a way to do this with flexbox, however, if we use `column-count` we can take advantage of the properties:

### [‘break-before’, ‘break-after’, ‘break-inside’](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-breaks)

In particular:

We can set `break-before: column;` on each 'head' element, where the *column* value means:

> Always force a column break before the generated box.

(similarly if we were using break-**after**:column this would force a column break **after** the generated box )

### **NB:** Browser support is currently [limited to IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) (!!)

```css
.grid {
    columns: 4;
    column-gap: 0;
}

.grid > div {
  background: lightyellow;
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
}

.grid .head {
  background: gold;
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
  break-before: column; /*   this is the vital rule  */
}

@media screen and (min-width:0\0) { 
    .grid {
        position: relative;
        left:-20vw;
        /* Probably because IE wants to add a column before the first head class?? 
        Interestingly enough though, the following selector does not work:
        .data + .head { break-before: column; } */
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="head">Column 1 (3 items)</div>
  <div>item 1-1</div>
  <div>item 1-2</div>
  <div>item 1-3</div>
  <div class="head">Column 2 (4 items)</div>
  <div>item 2-1</div>
  <div>item 2-2</div>
  <div>item 2-3</div>
  <div>item 2-4</div>
  <div class="head">Column 3 (2 items)</div>
  <div>item 3-1</div>
  <div>item 3-2</div>
  <div class="head">Column 4 (1 items)</div>
  <div>item 4-1</div>
</div>
```

--

Note that in the above fiddle for IE there seems to be a positioning issue (bug?) so I placed some code in a special media query that only effects IE so as not to effect other browsers

Comment: That's one step in right direction. The code works in chrome with `-webkit-column-break-before` while in IE it works inconsistently, depending on height of column items.

Comment: "Browser support is limited *to* IE" means for me that only IE supports this. I guess it's the inverse, but very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

If you can dynamically add a div before each head (except the first), it may be possible. Credits go to [Tobias Bjerrome Ahlin](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/). Tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE11.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #A2CBFA;
  border: 1px solid #4390E1;
  margin: 2px;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This parent has a fixed height - the request was for a solution without one.